# Giving error during connection to MySQL through TOAD

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

I want to import Excel data to MySQL.Usually I can successfully connect with MySQL through TOAD, but this time I am 
    getting following error.[image]

```
I am doing all this on VM by taking RDP.
Softwares used:
MySQL 5.5,
TOAD 7.3.1
```

Comment: the error seems quite clear - you can't use SSL to connect to the database. Use a non-encrypted connection instead

Comment: I was using TCP then also it was giving the same error. I am done with it by using updated version of Toad. (8.0)

Comment: Ok. Just to be clear, TCP is the transport layer, SSL is the security system, they are not alternative options. If you use SSL it might still connect using TCP, but just encrypt the connection.

Comment: Ya I know that ADyson, during connection also I was using TCP.